# how to delete row from database immediately in react js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am able to do axios.delete to remove an item from my database. But won’t be updated immediately unless I refresh the page or go to another page. here is the full component

```
function GestImages() {
//load Data from db
```

load data is working fine  :

> const [images, setImages]=useState([])
> useEffect(()=>{
> Axios.get("http://localhost:4000/produit/images")
> .then(res=>{
> setImages(res.data)
> })
> .catch(err=>{
> console.log(err.message)
> })
>
> },[])

```
   // delete Data from db 
    const deleteImage=(id,e)=>{
      Axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/produit/images/${id}`)
         .then((res)=>{
          setImages(prevImages => prevImages.filter(image =>  image.id !== id))
            
         })
         .catch(err=>{
           console.log(err.message)
         })
    }
    return (
       
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row row-a">
            <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 d-flex justify-content-between" style={{backgroundColor:'#000000'}}>
              <h1 className="justify-content-start" style={{color:'#FFFFFF'}}>Ajouter des images</h1>
            <Link to='/gest-images/add-images' style={{marginTop:"1%"}} ><button className="btn btn-primary justify-content-end">Ajouter</button></Link>
              </div>
              <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 ">
              
                <table className="table table-hover">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Produit Name</th>
                  <th scope="col">Image</th>
                  <th scope="col">Action</th>
                </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  {
                  images.map(images=>(
                  <tr key={images.id}>
                  <th>{images.produits.produitName}</th>
                  <td style={{width:"30%"}}><img src={"../../images/"+images.pathImage} style={{width:"20%"}} alt="produit img"/></td>
                  <td><button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={(e)=>deleteImage(images.id)}>Supprimer <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt} style={{color:"#FFFFFF"}}/> </button> </td>
                  </tr>
                  ))
                  }
                  </tbody>
                  </table>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              </div>
                      )
}

export default GestImages
```

Comment: Quick question: `image.id` and the `id` parameter in the `deleteImage` function have the same type? The problem might be that

Comment: share your full component!

Comment: yes they have the same type @luissmg

Comment: Can you try to use the callback on the hook? `setImages(prevImages => prevImages.filter(image =>  image.id !== id))`

Comment: @luissmg still the same the item was deleted in database but it still visible  but won’t be updated

Comment: Can you share how you are rendering the elements or all the component please? It's easier to understand the whole flow

Comment: @luissmg i  edited the whole question and i posted the whole component

Comment: The only weird part is this one: `images.map(images=>(`. You are using `images` again inside the loop. It should be `images.map(image=>(` and, of course, using `image` to render the content properly. Or did you copy it wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226660/discussion-between-luissmg-and-hamza-ben-ali).

Comment: If you add a dependency to `useEffect(()=>{ Axios.get("http://localhost:4000/produit/images") .then(res=>{ setImages(res.data) }) .catch(err=>{ console.log(err.message) })
},[])` it will told react to update